# Filter by letters or spaces in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to filter everything from a string other than letters or spaces by combining isLetter and isSpace conditions, but this didn't work.

```
normalise = filter (\x -> (Char.isLetter || Char.isSpace))
```

Is there a way to filter for one condition or another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing function application in your lambda. It should be:

```
normalise = filter (\x -> Char.isLetter x || Char.isSpace x)
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish `||` and `&&` were overloaded with an `a -> Bool` instance (and an `a -> b -> Bool` instance would be fun too), whereupon we could write `normalise = filter (isLetter||isSpace)`, but sadly, no.

Comment: The closest thing we have is `filter (liftA2 (||) isLetter isSpace)`. I don't know of any already-lifted `(||)` in the standard libraries though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using combinators like this:

```
import Control.Arrow
normalise = filter ((Char.isLetter &&& Char.isSpace) >>> uncurry (||))
```